# How to measure intersection between fractal and circle

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

Is there any known way to measure how many points in a circle do intersect a fractal (Koch, sierpinski,etc)?

Edit: generally there are infinite disconnected points in the intersection, so I imagine that some special measure must be needed to avoid trivial answers like "infinite points"